# peers detection in UDP java chatting application

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I'm writing a Java code for a small chatting application as a network course assignment. It should be one class (p2p)  only; not a (client/server). Every peer should connect to the chat and send/receive messages which must seen by all peers. I did the  code and it works between 2 machines as I assigned explicitly the IP address in my LAN for each machine and get response from each. What i need is:
1 - connect each peer to the socket once CONNECT button is hit.
2 - detect all connected peers and put them in a list ( array) .
3 - send all messages to all connected peers, so everybody seas everything.

Any help will be appreciated .
the code :

import javax.swing.*;

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class GUIExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener{  
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton b1;  
    JButton b2;  
    JLabel Name;
    JLabel port;
    JLabel HostName;
    JLabel Participants;
    JLabel Messages;
    JTextArea area;
    JTextPane pane;
    JTextPane pane1;
    JTextArea area1;
    JTextPane pane2;
    JTextArea area2;
    JTextField name;
    String s = "hi";
    JTextField p;
    JTextField IP;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


    GUIExample() throws Exception { 

         InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        Name = new JLabel ("NAME");
        Name.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
        add(Name);

        name = new JTextField();
        name.setBounds(100, 10, 200, 20);
        add(name);

        HostName=new JLabel("HostName");
        HostName.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
        add(HostName);

        IP = new JTextField(addr.getHostAddress());
        IP.setBounds(100, 50, 100, 20);
        add(IP);

        port = new JLabel("PORT");
        port.setBounds(220, 50, 100, 20);
        add(port);

        p = new JTextField();
        p.setBounds(280, 50, 100, 20);
        add(p);

        Participants = new JLabel("Participants");
        Participants.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 20);
        add(Participants);

        area=new JTextArea(300,300);  
        area.setBounds(10,150,200,300);  
        add(area);

        Messages = new JLabel ("Messages");
        Messages.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 20);
        add(Messages);

        area1=new JTextArea(200,300);  
        area1.setBounds(300,150,300,300);  
        add(area1);

        area2 = new JTextArea(100,100);
        area2.setBounds(10, 500, 500, 50);
        add(area2);

        b1=new JButton("connect");  
        b1.setBounds(600,50,80,30);  
        b1.addActionListener(this);  
        add(b1); 

        b2=new JButton("Send");  
        b2.setBounds(600,500,80,30);  
        b2.addActionListener(this);  
        add(b1);  
        add(b2);  

        setSize(750,575);  
        setLayout(null);  
        setVisible(true);  



    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b1)
        {
            if(name.getText().equals("") && IP.getText().equals(null) && !(p.getText().equals("11222"))){
                area1.append(" name or hostname or port fields are empty or invalid try again ");
            }
            else {
                area.append(name.getText());
                area1.append(name.getText()+ " is connected now \n");
                list.add(name.getText());
                list.add(IP.getText());
                list.add(p.getText());


            }
        }


        if(e.getSource() == b2)
        {
            BufferedReader inFromUser =
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                     (System.in));
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            } catch (SocketException e1) {
                System.out.println(" There is problem with Socek ");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            InetAddress IPAddress = null;
            try {
                byte[] ipp = new byte[]{(byte)192,(byte)168,1,48};
                IPAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipp);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                System.out.println(" There is problem with IP ");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
            area2.setText(sentence);
            sendData = sentence.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket =
               new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, 
                            IPAddress, 11222);
            try {
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("There is problem with Sending the packet");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(name.getText()!= null && area2.getText()!= null){
            area1.append(name.getText()+" : "+sentence+"\n");
            area2.setText(null);
            }
        }
    }  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Runnable task = () -> {         
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(11222);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

            while(true)
              {
                 DatagramPacket receivePacket =
                    new DatagramPacket(receiveData, 
                             receiveData.length);
                 try {
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                 String sentence = new String(
                             receivePacket.getData());
                 InetAddress IPAddress =
                             receivePacket.getAddress();
                 int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                     System.out.println("FROM Client:" +
                     sentence);
                 sendData = sentence.getBytes();
                 DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                 new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                          sendData.length, 
                             IPAddress, port);
                 try {
                    serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            };
            Thread thread = new Thread(task);
            thread.start();
        new GUIExample();  
    }

    }  


 is to detect all
```

Comment: This is exactly why you need a server. Without having central connection point, it's impossible to find out who else is out there

Comment: This is one reason why Multicasting was invented, and it has its limits.  If you're just sending Point-to-Point UDP, there's no way to find "peers" unless you have one already to connect to who can then report who he's connected to, and so on (or else happen to be in the unlikely situation where you can listen on the wire.)  But that still could leave nodes on their own.

Comment: Thnx 4 your suggestions. I've done it using SOCKET BROADCAST. It does the job 4 me as this is an assignment, and it is allowed to use any method BUT no client\server.